Identify a movie of a woman having imaginary child
I'd like to know the title of this movie. I think it's from 90's-2000's. Probably psychological thriller or SF. English language and subbed to my country language.
The movie is about a woman who is  believing that she has a child. She asks about her child to her neighbours, teachers and friends. But they say that she has no child. In one point of the movie, she meet a man that has the same condition to her. The man believes that he has a daughter??. I do not know if it's kind of disease, but the government is involved.

Flightplan is one such movie with a woman (played by Jodie Foster) looking for her seemingly non-existent daughter, but it all happens while aboard an airplane.

No. I have seen flight plan. It's not it.

This has to be it - "The Forgotten (2004)" 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forgotten_(2004_film)

Telly Paretta (Julianne Moore) believes that her son, Sam (Christopher Kovaleski), died fourteen months ago in a plane crash, but her husband Jim (Anthony Edwards) tells her that she's delusional and that they have never had a son. Dr. Munce (Gary Sinise) tells her that Sam was merely a figment of her imagination and is just imagining a life that might have been. He recommends that she be sent to a hospital, but she runs away and meets with a man named Ash (Dominic West). 
She thinks he is the father of a girl named Lauren (Kathryn Faughnan)
  who was friends with her son and died in the same crash. At first he
  dismisses her, claiming he never had a daughter, and calls the police.
  After she is taken into custody, however, he remembers his daughter
  and rescues Telly. Together they escape and go into hiding, pursued by
  National Security agents.

